# R markdown format, remove prefix

Tags: r, format, r-markdown

How can I remove the prefix like [1] when results are shown in R markdown?

e.g:

```
{r,comment=NA}
BRFSSdata=read.csv("/Users/chokiyoshizhen/Downloads/dso545/BRFSS.csv",header=T)
attach(BRFSSdata)
summary(height)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  48.00   64.00   67.00   67.18   70.00   93.00 
sd(height)
[1] 4.125954
```

Are there any ways to remove/suppress the [1], it's really frustrating.

Attached is csv file of sample raw data:
height weight gender
70     175    f
75     189    m
77     193    m

Comment: `cat(sd(height))`? Besides that, please get used to provide reproducible examples - no reader has got BRFSS.csv. (And welcome to SO. :-> )

Comment: It's really not a good idea to get into the habit of using `attach`

Comment: Thanks for your comment guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `writeLines()` to print without the prefix:

```
a <- 3; writeLines(c("Hello world!", a))
```

This gives you:

```
Hello world!
3
```

If you want to print computations in continuous text in an R markdown file you can use inline code blocks:

````
```{r,comment=NA}
BRFSSdata=read.csv("/Users/chokiyoshizhen/Downloads/dso545/BRFSS.csv",header=T)
attach(BRFSSdata)
summary(height)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
48.00   64.00   67.00   67.18   70.00   93.00 
```

`r sd(height)`
````

Comment: @BeichenLin I extended my answer. Let me know if that solves your problem.